# smell some bad smell

Tags: word-usage

Someone farts in the class.

Jack noticed that and said, "What's that smell?"

Keith haven't smelled that and asked Jack, "Smell, I didn't smell anything."

Jack said, ***"I smell stinks." or "I smell some bad smell."***

Smell can be verb and noun, how do we used it?

Comment: *I smell something very bad*

Answer (score 1):

It can also be an adjective:

**Noun**:

> "What is that **smell**? It stinks!"

**Verb**:

> "Can you **smell** that? It stinks!"

or

> "**Smell** this. It smells good."

**Adjective**:

> "It's very **smelly** in here. In fact, it stinks."

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's right to say "I smell stinks"; "I smell something stinky" would be OK. While "smell" can be a noun or a verb, "stink" is only a verb.

Comment: No, stink is often used as a noun. Example: The stink is from the skunk spraying the house.